# Images not displayed when displaying HTML document with WebClient?

Tags: c#, html, browser, httprequest

I have been developing a web browser that communicates with a relay (using TCP connections). The relay makes the request to the specified URL. The relay then writes the downloaded document to the TCP stream and the client web browser reads it. However, when the client reads the html document returns and displays it in a WebBrowser control, it does not load the images or CSS styles as they are linked relative to the web page.

I believe the problem is this. If a page at the following url had this markup:

```
<img src="bg.png" />
```

(http://foo.bar/foobar.html)

rather than looking at http://foo.bar/bg.png, the web browser does not know where to find the picture or style so instead will look for just bg.png (which is obviously not found). However, this raises the question on how web pages are dynamically loaded when using the 'Webbrowser.Navigate(string)' method with images also.

Could anyone outline how this is done when loading html documents into WebBrowsers.

I use this code to load the html string to the web browser:

```
wb.DocumentText="0";
wb.OpenNew(true);
wb.Write("HTML");
wb.Refresh();
```

Comment: The webbrowser control expects the image file to be in the same location as the application itself - actually you're telling the control that. The control itself is a rather simplified version of IE and will not download the images when you don't provide a path from where to download. Specify the full (URL-) path and it will show CSS + images.

Comment: @Leon Thanks for the idea but how would I go about doing this?